# Customize log4j in unit testing from IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, log4j

I'd like to customize some junit logs from the IntelliJ IDE.

I have a sample IntelliJ Maven project.  My goal is to be able to configure the logs for `src/test/java`.

From my understanding, the convention for the log4j configuration is to place it in:

- `src/test/resources/log4j.properties`
- IntelliJ automatically recognizes the `src/test/resources/` as a Maven resources directory.
- I've also tried to add the `log4j.properties` file to the root `test` and `src` directories, both to no avail.

My unit test looks like this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LogTest {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LogTest.class);

    @Test
    public void printLogs() {
        log.info("Hello world from log.info!");
        log.error("Hello world from log.error!");
    }
}
```

My `src/test/resources/log4j.properties` looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL
```

... however the output never shows the `log.info` line.

```
00:48:19.766 [main] ERROR LogTest - Hello world from log.error!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

... so I'm stuck at the very first first step of configuring my unit test logs.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm happy to share the `pom.xml` and/or IntelliJ project if needed.  It's the default Maven project that IntelliJ provides with dependencies for `junit`, `log4j-api`, and `log4j-core` added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a facepalm moment, but I went back and [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)'d and these are the two mistakes (and fixes)

1. It's called `log4j2.properties`, not `log4j.properties` emphasis on the `2`.

   ```
   src/test/resources/log4j2.properties
                           ^------------ the number two is needed
   ```
2. There's no `log4j` prefix on the properties.

   ```
   # BEFORE
   log4j.rootLogger=...
   #    ^------------ remove the "log4j." prefix


   # AFTER
   rootLogger=...
   ```

Now there is a working IntelliJ and customizable log4j.

Although these may be obvious to some, I'm leaving both the question and answer here because a lot of time was wasted on these small details and I'm hoping it will save others some time.

Comment: log4j version 2 was a major refactoring by the Apache logging team, abandoning version 1 as the original primary developer had left to create logback based on the log4j version 1.3 work.   He later decided to fork the abandoned version into reload4j (https://reload4j.qos.ch/).   This is why log4j2 is so different from log4j version 1.2.

Comment: Thanks kindly for the history.  I'm sure that the project had well-justified reasoning for changing things, however in my opinion, there too many similarities and not enough tripwires for developers to not hit snags.  For example, based on my searching `rootLogger` was reused, but the `log4j.` prefix was removed.  Furthemore, changing the `.properties` namespace would only seem sensible if projects were simultaneously running Log4j 1 + 2 simultaneously (which I assume should never happen).

Comment: ... furthemore, some of Google's first results, such as this one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/log4j-properties-file-example are artificatially dated for 2022 (comments suggest this is a lie) which turns an otherwise simply copy/paste into hours of trial and error.

Comment: I do not know why they did as they did with version 2, but logback has greater traction than log4j2 so if it doesn't matter to you, either use java.util.logging (built in, enhanced a lot in Java 8) or slf4j with logback.  This is the default for Spring Boot applications.

Comment: Thanks.  Personally, I moved away fro slf4j when switching to Log4J2, as everything broke, which defeated the purpose of slf4j to begin with :D... but thanks for the pointer, I'll reconsider as well as give Java 8's Logger a look.

Comment: Given your current problem it may have had the same cause, namely that you used documentation for the older version.  That said, at one point slf4j enforced that all parameters should be strings instead of objects which bluntly said was a mistake.  This mean you cannot log complex objects without converting them to a string first.  My guess would be that the native log4j2 interface does not make this mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately the conversation of why I switched from slf4j to Log4J2 was lost when Slack changed its retention settings from 10,000 messages to 90 days so I've lost that trial and error context, but my colleague at the time was so frustrated that we ripped sl4j out entirely, touching 106 files. :( https://github.com/qzind/tray/pull/896/files.

Comment: As can be seen on  https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/graphs/contributors slf4j is essentially a single-man-army effort which mean that the design changes does not have to be approved by a full team before being implemented.